# Python rsa module - how to use existing public key

Tags: python, rsa

I am trying to use rsa module (pip install rsa) to load an existing public key and use it to verify the signature of some data. Is there any example or sample code ? I am not finding any sample on how to load an existing public key and use it to verify signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I was able to figure this out, thanks.

```
   try:
       rsaPubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(myPubKey)
       result = rsa.verify(signedData, base64.b64decode(signature), rsaPubKey)
       print "Signature Verification result: %s" %(result)
   except:
       e = sys.exc_info()[0]
       print "Error - signature verification failed %s" %(e)
```